# Нужна ли запятая как уточнение местоположения?

Tags: пунктуация

В Севастополе на пересечении улиц Частника и Щорса несколько месяцев назад образовалась глубокая лужа.

Comment: Возможно, пригодится: http://www.gramota.ru/class/coach/punct/45_179

Answer (score 2):

В Севастополе, **на пересечении улиц Частника и Щорса,** несколько месяцев назад образовалась глубокая лужа.

Это **уточняющее обстоятельства места, требуется обособление**. Обособлению также способствует распространенность обстоятельства и наличие неоднородного обстоятельства времени.